# Listview a Textview en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, eclipse

Desarrollo una apliacion movil en [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio) tengo un `ListView` y quiero obtener el evento en el cual cuando seleccione un Item de la lista yo muestre un determinado `String` en un `TextView`.

**Por Ejemplo:**

1. Seleccion en Item A presenta en `TextView1` el `String1`
2. Seleccion en Item B presenta en `TextView1` el `String2`

Por ahora ya puedo presentar los datos pero cargando una `Activity` con un `TexView` para cada Item.

¿Como puedo hacer que funcione de forma dinámica para todos mis Items?

Comment: Podrias enseñarnos el codigo que ya tienes y que has intentado?

Comment: Hola Luis bienvenido a StackOverflow, podrias agregar tu codigo para que podamos ayudarte no olvides colocarlo dentro de {} para que el editor pueda reconocer que es codigo. En concreto creo que necesitas hacer uso de esa activity en la que muestras tus datos de forma dinamica para que no necesitas crear una por cada item, pero viendo tu codigo sera mas facil. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Define el listener `OnItemClickListener()` a tu ListView para detectar el evento al dar clic a un elemento de la lista, al seleccionar el item A podemos definir que es el primero y tendría la posición 0, y el item B el segundo la posición 1; de acuerdo a la selección del item, agregas el texto deseado en tu `TextView`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:  //Seleccion item A
                miTextView1.setText("Texto String1");
                break;
            case 1: //Seleccion item  B
                miTextView1.setText("Texto String2");
                break;
            default:
                miTextView1.setText("");
        }


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías relizarlo asignando un nuevo método al ListView:

listView.setOnItemClickListener

con este metodo obtienes el objeto de la fila y después mediante sus atributos puedes pintar el texto que desees en cualquier componente.

¡Mucha Suerte! :D